# WPF Combobox loses binding to SelectedItem when changing the view model

Tags: wpf

I have a combo box that changes the objects type.  When a new type is selected I destroy the old view model and bind to the new view model.  When I do this the combo box no longer updates the selected item property.

The Combo box declaration looks like this.  Please note that this combobox is in the ItemTemplate of a ListView.

```
<ListView ItemSource="{Binding MyViewModels}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="viewModels:MyTypeViewModel">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Type:" Width="170"/>
                <ComboBox  SelectedItem="{Binding Type}"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyEnumTypes}}"
                                          Width="150"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The property that is losing its binding looks like this.  Please note that I do not call OnPropertyChanged because the class uses the Fody.PropertyChanged package and the class is marked with [ImplementsPropertyChanged].

```
    public MyType Type { get; set; }
    {
        get { return _type; }
        set
        {
            if (_type == value) return;

            _type = value;

            OnMyTypeChanged?.Invoke(this, new MyTypeChangedEventArgs(_type));
        }
    }
```

The type changed callback looks like this.

```
    private void OnMyTypeChanged(object sender, MyTypeChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var index = MyViewModels.IndexOf(sender as MyViewModel);

        var selected = SelectedMyViewModel == MyViewModels[index]; 

        var tmp = CreateReplacementViewModelByType(args.Type, MyViewModels[index].Model.Address);

        if (selected)
            SelectedMyViewModel = tmp;

        MyViewModels[index] = tmp;

        MyViewModels[index].OnMyTypeChanged += OnMyTypeChanged;
    }
```

The first time I change the type of the object the viewmodel updates correctly.  After that changing the selected item of the combobox does not even call the Set function of the property.  Somehow the combobox is maintaining its old binding.

The DataContext of my view is assigned once at the start of the program in code behind.  The context itself is a singleton manager class that does the actual swapping of the view models.  The initialization looks like this.  It is not updated otherwise.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Set the global DataContext
        DataContext = MyTypeManager.Instance;
    }
```

The MyViewModels property is declared in the manager class as an observablecollection as follows:

```
    public ObservableCollection<MyViewModel> MyViewModels { get; } = new ObservableCollection<MyViewModel>();
```

I have created a test application in visual studio 2015 a link to the repository is here. https://github.com/df424/WFPComboBoxTest

Comment: How do you set the `DataContext` of your view? Please provide us with a [mcve].

Comment: I have modified the post to include the information about where the DataContext is set.

Comment: please post MyViewModels property

Comment: I updated the post with this part.

Comment: @ghost You don't call the CollectionChanged event after changing the contents. That could be causing the UI to not rebind to the new entity.

Comment: The Fody.PropertyChanged add on takes care of CollectionChanged and PropertyChanged events automatically.

Comment: Its not a collection changed event when an item is changed or updated. The collection has not changed. CollectionChanged handles adding and removing elements. Try calling it in the OnMyTypeChanged for your MyViewModels property.

Comment: According to the documentation the CollectionChanged event is fired in an ObservableCollection when an item is added, removed, moved or replaced.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375(v=vs.110).aspx I did however subscribe to the event manually to make sure it was being called.  It is called on the first change during the replace.  I also tried invoking the collection changed event manually after the replace.  This did not have any effect.

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was incorrect, anyhow, can you provide a repo for the behaviour? A working example as it were?

Comment: I have updated the post with a link to a github repository.  I cannot provide the real code as the source is proprietary and it is hundreds of files anyway.  The brief example does exhibit the same behavior however.  If you set a break point on the Type property in the view model and change one of the comboboxes you will see the set property is only called the first time and is unbound after changing the view model.

Answer (score 0):

To bind to Enum datasources first add a ResourceDictionary with the following

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:utility="clr-namespace:MyApp;assembly=MyApp">
  <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="MyEnumTypesSource" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
      <x:Type TypeName="MyApp:MyEnumTypes" />
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
  </ObjectDataProvider>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then add the resource dictionary to your window or app

```
<Window.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/EnumDataSources.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

And finally add your ComboBox binding as follows

```
<ComboBox Height="24" Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyEnumTypesSource}}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding MyViewModel.MyCurrentEnumValue}" />
```

The ViewModel property should just basically be something like the following.

```
public MyApp.MyEnumTypes MyCurrentEnumValue
{
    get { return m_MyCurrentEnumValue; }
    set
    {
        m_MyCurrentEnumValue = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MyCurrentEnumValue");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi bic,  Thanks for your response.  The enum is appearing as options in the combo box as intended.  There is also no problem reflecting the current state of the property.  The issue comes when I switch view models.  Once this is done selecting a new value in the combo box no longer makes a call to the set function of the Type property.  Interestingly enough there are other properties in the class I have not included that still update correctly.